# Understanding the terms iteratee, callback, function factory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, factory, terminology, loops

I am trying to become a little bit familiar with the JavaScript terminology. I think I am confused with the terms **iteratee**, **callback** and **function factory**

Let me use the following silly example:

```
//this function accept an array and then  returns a new array that
//contains the elements of the first array altered by func
function mapForEach(arr, func) {
   var newArr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(func(arr[i]));
  }
 return newArr;
}

//this function multiplies two numbers
var multiply = function (a, b) {
 console.log(a * b);
};

//this is a silly function that passes a multiplier as the first
//argument of the multiply function
var multiplyBy = function(multiplier) {
 return multiply.bind(this, multiplier);
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3];

mapForEach(arr, multiplyBy(3)); //[6, 10, 20]
```

So, to *my* understanding thus far:

- **iteratee** (aka **predicate**) is a function object that does some work. In this example `mapForEach` accept a `func` object to do some work with the `arr` elements, so **`func` can be called *iteratee*** and hence **`multiplyBy` is an *iteratee***. In a general concept maybe **`multiply` can also be considered an *iteratee*** as is a standalone function that performs a basic work.
- **callback** is a function A you give to another function B to be invoked by the other function (so, the other function B --sort to speak-- "calls back" the function A). In this example when `mapForEach` is called, is executed in a new environment where it calls back the `func` function object. So the **`func` object can also be called a *callback***. However, in the same context, `mapForEach` can also be considered as a function that, when is executed, calls back the `multiplyBy` function, i.e. **`multiplyBy` is a *callback* too**.
- **function factory** we call a function that does some work for us and/or return a value (i.e an array, object, function object, whatever....). In our example `multiplyBy` is a function object that when it is called it returns (a copy of) another function object (`multiply`) that has the `multiplier` parameter in its closure. Thus **`multiplyBy` is a *factory function***.

Am I getting all these right, (or am I going insane :-P)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iteratee is not a function that just does some work. It has to do some work on an iterable set, an array for example. A predicate is a function that takes an argument and returns true/false, predicates are for example used for filtering iterable sets. Thus, iteratee and predicate are definitely not the same.

Function factory is not just a function that does some work and returns a value. It is a function that is capable of creating a family of other functions based on supplied arguments.

The `multiplyBy` is not a callback "per se", the `func` passed to `mapForEach` is. The `multiplyBy` becomes a callback when you pass it to another method that calls it back.